# Html <code> with placeholder

Tags: html, css, haml

How I need add **placeholder** attribute to **< code> < /code>** tag like in **< input> < /input>**?

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have placeholders in `<code></code>` as it's not an input field... You might want to use a `<textarea placeholder="your placeholder"></textarea>` for inputing code...

[Example showing the difference here](https://jsbin.com/xoyiyo/edit)